# Invoking function expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm following a React-hooks tutorial and I don't understand why does the function expression, `timerId` in the top `useEffect` is being invoked automatically, but the function expression, `search`, in the bottom `useEffect` requires it to be called `search()` in order to invoke it?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedTerm(term);
    }, 1500);
 
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    };
  }, [term]);
 
  useEffect (() => {
    const search = async() => {
      const { data } = await axios.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php', {
        params: {
          action: 'query', 
          list: 'search',
          origin: '*',
          format: 'json', 
          srsearch: debouncedTerm
        }
      });
      setResults(data.query.search);
    };
    search();
  }, [debouncedTerm]);
```

Comment: Its invoked after 1.5 seconds because you pass it to setTimeout.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is assigning a function to `search` variable which needs to be invoked manually.

However in the body of other useEffect it is invoking the `setTimeout` function and assigning the return value of `setTimeout` function to `timerId` variable. Return value of `setTimeout` function is a positive integer which is the unique identifier of the timeout.

So the value of `timerId` is not a function to begin with. It's the id of the timeout.

Only function that is being invoked in the body of top useEffect is the `setTimeout` function.